# Does anyone have a routine example implementation of Numerical Recipes 3rd Ed estep/mstep find in gaumixmod.h header?

Tags: c++, gaussian, expectation-maximization

I'm starting with the use of "Numerical Recipes 3ed", and I would like to implement the "estep" and "mstep" of the chapter 16, I can't find examples to help me and allow me to get started without difficulty and manage to exploit the gaumixmod.h library.

Comment: Doesn't NR come with an implementation of all methods discussed in the book?

Comment: In the previous edition (2nd) of the book, there is another example book for the implementations, but in 3rd edition, i can't stand the equivalent example book. If you have some reference or details, it will be very helpful.

Comment: the books are online: http://numerical.recipes/. I think for free you only get limited access to some pages per month, but if you are looking for something specific that might be sufficient

Comment: Right, I just want to run library into chapter 16, specially gaumixmod.h.